# generate C structures from high level definition of objects

Tags: c, perl, auto-generate

I have to define high level definition of objects such as :

```
obj1 => [
    name => "object1",
    type => "uint64",
    dependents => [
         {type  => "unit32", name => "dep1"},
         {type  => "uint32", name => "dep2"}
    ],
    default_value = "100"
]
```

From this I want to generate the C structures and some helper routines such as:

```
struct_dependents {
    int type;
    char name[MAX];
}

struct struct_obj1 {
     char name[MAX];
     int  type;
     struct dependents deps[MAX_DEP];
     unit64 default_value;
}

// Some initializations..
```

Earlier I thought I could define the high level objects in .pm (perl module) files and then use perl to generate C code, but writing code to generate C code this way might be error prone and tough to maintain if object definitions change in future.

What I want to know is that - are there any such ready  made tools which allow us to write high level object definition and auto generate their C structures?

Comment: Why would it be error prone? Why do you need to define C structures in something other than C? Why would there be tools that understand your definition language, or what are you looking in a definition language?

Comment: the idea is to expose the high level object definition to wider audience (even customers) for their quick understanding, for this we don't want to expose C code.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of code generators for C - you're more likely to find something that uses an intermediary syntax such as xml; A quick google turned up [xml2c](http://acme.com/software/xml2c/). You can use XML::Simple for saving your hashes to xml.

More [examples](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=generate+c+code+from+xml) can be found on google.

If you wish to roll out your own, code generation using template toolkit provides a [flexible](http://perl-node-interface.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/source-code-generation-with-template.html) approach.